# ADA - Searching a directory with a pattern - not returning as it should

Tags: directory, ada

This section of my program is supposed to list all files within the directory containing ".txt" in the name but it's not returning anything when run. If I delete ".txt" and leave it as an empty string "" then it works perfectly and returns all file names including the .txt files so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
  procedure Search_Directory is
      use Ada.Directories;
      
      procedure Write_Search_Item(Search_Item : in Directory_Entry_Type) is
      begin
         Put(Item => Simple_Name(Directory_Entry => Search_Item));
         New_Line;
      end Write_Search_Item;

      Filter : Constant Filter_Type := (Ordinary_File => True,
                                        Special_File => False,
                                        Directory => True);         
   begin
      Search(Directory => Current_Directory,
             Pattern => (".txt"),
             Filter => Filter,
             Process => Write_Search_Item'Access);           
   end Search_Directory;
```

Comment: You could try `*.txt`.

Comment: Yes, that works now, thank you

Comment: Your OS probably has a program to list files that match a pattern (`dir` for DOS/Windows and `ls` for Unix-based OSes). We'll call that program `<c>`. What would `<c> .txt` do on your system? What pattern would you use to match all files containing `.txt`? You should give that same pattern to `Search`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Search` function, defined in the package `Ada.Directories`, takes a pattern argument which is either a null string or a form that is implementation-defined [RM A.16 (111/ 2)](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-16.html#p111). In GNAT, this pattern is supposed to be a regular expression (see also [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Implementation-Defined-Characteristics.html#Implementation-Defined-Characteristics)) described in `System.Regexp` (see also [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/libgnat/s-regexp.ads;h=243da6775231a4953e0eabe8af779ba73748ec02;hb=HEAD), second grammar, a "globbing pattern").